'were' or 'was' in a sentence with two subjects - plural followed by singular
I have a sentence that goes somewhat like this:
No further oranges or information <were/was> given.
Now, I know that usually we use 'were' in cases like this where there are two subjects in the sentence. However, I cannot help but feel like 'were' sounds awfully unnatural in this application, and 'was' flows much better.
I also cannot decide if 'or' conjoins subjects where 'and' does not - perhaps this is the difference contributing to the unnatural sounding 'were'.
Any opinions?

Were doesn't seem unnatural to me.

related: 1 Singular or plural following a list 2 Mixing plural and singular list items with a single verb 3 Cabbage and beets together sounds good." or "Cabbage and beets together sound good." 4 Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And

People tend not to discuss "oranges or information" but I found several results for "facts or information", and it generally is followed by a plural noun:

Facts or information are used to validate alternatives or options intended for action. (Cow Up a Tree: Knowing and Learning for Change in Agriculture. Case Studies from Industrialised Countries. LEARN Group, 2000)


Copyright does not protect facts or information ... but it may protect the manner in which such facts or information are expressed (Creative Expression : An Introduction to Copyright and Related Rights for Small and Medium-sized Enterprises. World Intellectual Property Organization, 2023)


If facts or information are lacking to substantiate a hypothesis (An Introduction to Epidemiology. Thomas C. Timmreck, Jones and Bartlett Publishers, 2002)


... the rule that ideas, facts, or information are not copyrightable (Geographic Information Science: Mastering the Legal Issues, George Cho, Wiley, 2005)


Analytical research: where facts or information are used to analyse or critically evaluate the data. (Editage)

However in English a lot depends on logic as well as grammatical number, i.e. your sense of whether things are more like one thing or many things, so with two clearly singular nouns linked by "or", it would be a singular verb:

A cat or a dog is a pet. (Essential English Skills for the Australian Curriculum Year 9: A Multi-level Approach. Anne-Marie Brownhill, Alison Rucco, Deborah Simpson. Cambridge University Press. 2016)


Google Ngrams is less clear about the comparison "facts or information are" and "facts or information is"

Probably complements tchrist's answer at the duplicate. If you agree, best to post it there.

I would agree with the first response; "were" sounds correct.
To me, saying it the other way seems just as wrong as saying "no further oranges was given."
The sentence itself is awkward, and it flows much better when "information" precedes "oranges." Perhaps it is the position of the singular "information" that is causing "were" to sound unnatural to you.
